# User-input seed for AES encryption in Java

Tags: java, aes, seed

So I've been coding this program that encrypts a file and then decrypts it, and I want the pseudo-random key generator to take in user input as seed, so that the key can be created from it. Note that I want the key to be string-dependent (i.e.: if I enter the seed "hello" several times, it will encrypt the file with the same key every time), because eventually I will be splitting the encrypt & decrypt functions into two files.

This is my first try, based on SecureRandom. There is more code, but only main is relevant:

```
protected static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";

public static void main(String args[]) {

    String stringKey = args[1];
    byte[] seedArray = stringKey.getBytes();
    SecureRandom sRandom = new SecureRandom(seedArray);
    byte[] keyArray = new byte[16];
    SecretKey sKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyArray, ALGORITHM);

    try
    {   

        Encrypter2 encrypter = new Encrypter2(sKey);

        FileInputStream efis = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        FileOutputStream efos = new FileOutputStream("Encrypted");
        encrypter.encrypt(efis, efos);

        FileInputStream dfis = new FileInputStream("Encrypted");
        FileOutputStream dfos = new FileOutputStream("Decrypted.txt");
        encrypter.decrypt(dfis, dfos);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Now this will create a unique key for a string input in Java 1.7, but it randomizes in Java 1.6. Is there another method of generating a user-seeded key that is dependent on the string the user inputs? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you really want for AES encryption is 16 (or 32) bytes of data to use as a Secret Key.  Here, you are taking user supplied bytes, using them as the seed for a random byte generator, and then generating some random bytes.

Instead, you can generate the bytes directly from the user supplied String without using SecureRandom.  Using a "One-way" hashing algorithm (like SHA, which stands for Secure Hashing Algorithm), you can turn the user supplied String into the number of bytes you need.  The generated bytes will always be the same if the user supplied String is the same, regardless of JVM.